# What do you mean by initializer? Is it a process or it is a noun?

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm reading the officital Swift documents "The Swift Programming language (Swift 2.2)". In the topics of **Optionals** under **the Baseics** section
I found the following descriptions which has somthing to do with initializer.

"*The example below uses the initializer to try to convert a String into an Int:*

```
 let possibleNumber = "123"
 let convertedNumber = Int(possibleNumber)
```

*Because the initializer might fail, it returns an optional Int, rather than an Int*."

I wonder what exaclty the initializer means. Is it the object **convertedNumver** is acturally the initializer or the string **"123"** or the whole process is called the initializer. Can someone please explain it for me?

Thanks A lot

Sl

Comment: the `Int(...)` is the initializer since it eventually initializes an `Int`.

Comment: @luk2302 Can I say like so, the Int(...) is the initializer and it initilizes a optional Int value to the object "convertedNumber"

Comment: @luk2302 alles ist gut, vielen Dank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertedNumber` is an Object. `Int(...)` actually initialize the `convertedNumber` Object for you. As conversion `String` to `Int` is not guaranteed to success, `convertedNumber` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Initializer is a method which used to initialize an object after creation and to set initial values for the data members. Every class should have an initializer (can have more) to initializer to initialize its objects.

In your case `Int("")` is an initializer method which takes a string and try(as string can not convert to int all the time so its an optional) to convert it into Int object.

Please read this [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) to understand more about Initializers

Comment: *initialization* is a process. *initializer* is not a process.